# Convert a matrix to an xts object

Tags: r, xts

I am new to R and need to use the function `getnfac` from the `PANICr` package. And it seems that the function only takes an `xts` object as its first argument. However, after I went through some reading I still don't understand what an `xts` object is. Could anyone please tell me how I can convert a `matrix` into an `xts` object?

Below I use `return` matrix as the first argument. Therefore I just need to convert `return` to an `xts` object.

```
getnfac(return,143,"BIC3")
Error in getnfac(return, 143, "BIC3") : 
  x must be an xts object so lags and differences are taken properly
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xts` is an extensible time series object, essentially a regular `ts` object (or more correctly a `zoo` object) with some bits added.
The 'extensible' part of the name refers to how you can add attributes of your own choice.

While a `matrix` can be converted into a multivariate time series quite easily

```
m <- matrix(1:16, 4)
m.ts <- ts(m)
index(m.ts)
```

An `xts` requires its index (a vector describing at what time each sample was taken) to be in a date or time format

```
library(xts)
m <- matrix(1:16, 4)
d <- as.Date(1:nrow(m))
m.xts <- xts(m, order.by=d)
index(m.xts)
```

If your data is sampled at evenly spaced intervals a dummy index like the one above is probably ok. If not, you'll need to supply a vector corresponding to the sampling times.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the first argument to the `getnfac()` function should be matrix containing the data.

In addition to the above answers,
You can convert matrix format using `coredata()` about `xts` object.

Comment: In your opinion? To quote the source code of `getnfac`, 4th line: `is.xts(x) || stop("x must be an xts object so lags and differences are taken properly")`. No two ways about it, supply an `xts` object, or the process will be stopped.

Comment: @AkselA I assume he meant he thinks the API design should take a matrix.  This answer should really be a comment on the question... but IIRC you need 20 rep to be allowed to leave comments.

BTW, `coredata()` is to convert xts to matrix, whereas what is being asked here is how to convert matrix to xts.